# Do I need to caulk the walls and around tub of my shower all at the same time?

Tags: bathroom, tile, caulking

I caulked two sides of my tub surround last night and waited a day to caulk the long wall, is this ok or was i supposed to caulk all sides and corners at the same time to ensure there is no leakage?

Answer (score 1):

In a perfect world you would want to but you don't have to.  The silicone is mainly bonding to the materials around the gap, which is generally your tub and walls.  It doesn't matter in that case at all.

The only point that matters is the silicone connectivity between your silicone and old silicone.  This is a very small connection.  On [GE's website](http://www.caulkyourhome.com/frequently-asked-questions.php) you can read that silicone does indeed bond with dried silicone.  It however says that bond is not as good as what you would get with two wet bonds - obviously.  But still works.  If your silicone was not all the way dry probably even better for you.

I wouldn't worry about it.  Silicone bonds well and lasts a while.  Maybe just keep an eye out for the area that you connected on.  But really no big deal at all.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think caulk is waterproof or recommended for bathrooms as it is susceptible to mould growth; ideally you want a silicone based waterproof sealant around the edge of the bathtub.

Ideally something like this [silicone sealant](http://www.wickes.co.uk/Kitchen+Bathroom-Sealant-Clear-310ml/p/243002), but it is perfectly possible to get it in other colours too. White and translucent seem to be the most prevalent though in most DIY places.

Comment: I used silicone sealant around the tub before tiling. I used this product from home depot till fill the gap between the tile and tub.  http://www.homedepot.com/p/Custom-Building-Products-Polyblend-10-Antique-White-10-5-oz-Non-Sanded-Ceramic-Tile-Caulk-PC1010N/100678074

Comment: In which case, you should be ok. As long as there is a watertight seal underneath, the caulk will dry over time, just like regular plaster. There is no need to do it in one go. Your caulk is silicone based too and it is perfect for bathroom use, as it wont grow mould.